# Manage value inside multidimensional list

Tags: python, string, list, variables

How can I Manage string value inside multidimensional list?

I know Python Strings is Immutable once created. But I have try to convert it from tuple to list and remove it from multidimensional list then adding back but still no luck.

This is what I try :

```
for b_order in list(signal_order_correction):
print repr(b_order)
for a_order in list(signal_order_position):
    print "A order second" + repr(a_order)
    if (a_order[0][0] == b_order[0][0] and a_order[0][1] == b_order[0][1] and a_order[0][4] == b_order[0][4]):
        print "Correcting"
        signal_order_position = signal_order_position.remove(a_order)
        a_order = list(a_order[0])
        a_order[0][5] = str(a_order[0][5])
        # print "repr a"
        # print repr(a_order)
        print repr(a_order[5])
        # a_order[5] = None
        # a_order[6] = None
        # print repr(a_order)
        a_order[0][5] = b_order[0][5]
        a_order[0][6] = b_order[0][6]
        a_order = tuple(a_order)
        print "corrected by order correction"
        signal_order_position = signal_order_position.append(a_order)
```

but its gives me error

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example ? of input and expected output ?

Comment: Python strings are immutable and cannot be changed. The error means you are trying to change characters inside the string, which is not doable. You can use a byte array if this is what you want.

Comment: @TonyTannous I expect I can assign string inside `a_order[0][5]` from `b_order[0][5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved my own question by using remove and append method :

```
        for b_order in list(signal_order_correction):
            print repr(b_order)
            for a_order in list(signal_order_position):
                print "A order second" + repr(a_order)
                if (a_order[0][0] == b_order[0][0] and a_order[0][1] == b_order[0][1] and a_order[0][4] == b_order[0][4]):
                    print "Correcting"
                    signal_order_position.remove(a_order)
                    print "corrected by order correction"
                    signal_order_position.append(b_order)
```